# I am trying to create an EKS cluster with cluster.yaml deployment.yaml and service.yaml but nodeSelector is not working as expected

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks, eksctl

I am trying to create an EKS cluster which has Jenkins running on Jenkins nodes and Nexus running on Nexus nodes for this I am trying to use nodeSelector which is not working as expected I don't understand which part I am missing.

My cluster.yaml for creating the EKS cluster is as follows:

```
apiVersion: eksctl.io/v1alpha5
kind: ClusterConfig
metadata:
  name: Devops-Test
  region: ap-south-1

vpc:
  id: vpc-xxxxxx
  cidr: "192.168.0.0/16"
  subnets:
    public:
      ap-south-1a:
        id: subnet-xxxx
      ap-south-1b:
        id: subnet-xxxx
    private:
      ap-south-1a:
        id: subnet-xxxx
      ap-south-1b:
        id: subnet-xxxx

nodeGroups:
  - name: jenkins-public-node-group
    tags: { role: "jenkins" }
    instanceType: t2.medium
    desiredCapacity: 2
  - name: jenkins-private-node-group
    tags: { role: "jenkins" }
    instanceType: t2.medium
    desiredCapacity: 2
    privateNetworking: true
  - name: nexus-public-node-group
    tags: { role: "nexus" }
    instanceType: t2.medium
    desiredCapacity: 2
  - name: nexus-private-node-group
    tags: { role: "nexus" }
    instanceType: t2.medium
    desiredCapacity: 2
    privateNetworking: true
```

My deployment.yaml is as follows

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: devops-tools
  namespace: devops
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      role: jenkins 
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        role: jenkins
    spec:
      nodeSelector:
        role: jenkins
      containers:
        - name: jenkins
          image: jenkins:2.60.3
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
```

Finally my service.yaml is as follows

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: jenkins-service
  namespace: devops
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    role: jenkins
  ports:
    - nodePort: 31429
      port: 8080
      targetPort: 8080
```

I am expecting Jenkins to run only on nodes tagged with role:jenkins but it is also running on nodes without that tag I have even tried applying label with

kubectl label nodes  role=jenkins

and then applying deployment.yaml but deployment still happens on nodes without that label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `labels` instead of `tags` in your `cluster.yaml` file.
See these [docs](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/managing-workflow-runs/manually-running-a-workflow) for more information.

Tags apply to AWS tags, which are irrelevant to Kubernetes. Only labels are relevant when trying to apply node selectors.

BTW - you should also make sure that your node selectors are applied as [prescribed](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-pods-nodes/#create-a-pod-that-gets-scheduled-to-your-chosen-node) to your pods - since pods shouldn't be allowed on nodes without the specified label. From the behavior you are describing - it seems like the pods are being created without a node selector at all.